# Clusters disappearing when using minpoints > 2 in ST_ClusterDBSCAN

Tags: postgis

I'm using ST_ClusterDBSCAN to cluster polygons. I'm familiar with the algorithm (or so I thought) but the results of the PostGIS implementation are confusing me. When running it with `minpoints` larger than 2, many of the clusters simply vanish, despite these very same clusters being present in a previous `minpoints=2` run while having more than the specified `minpoints` number of features.

Here is an example using a subset of my complete data. The top image is a clustering done with `eps=5` and `minpoints=2`. The bottom image is the same clustering, but with `minpoints=5`:

### `minpoints=2`

[image]

### `minpoints=5`

[image]

Notice how the dark blue cluster in the first image disappears when `minpoints` is raised to 5, despite there being 12 features in the first case. `eps` was not changed.

Am I missing a crucial detail in the algorithm or its implementation? Why are these clusters vanishing? I know that DBSCAN is not technically 100% deterministic but I would think that obvious clusters like this just straight-up vanishing is wrong.

So far as a workaround I just run it with `minpoints=2` and then filter the results afterwards so exclude clusters with less than my actually desired `minpoints` value. But this is cumbersome and inefficient when scaling up.

I am using:

- Postgres 11.2
- PostGIS 2.5.2
- GEOS 3.5.1

Here is some sample code to try it out on this data sample:

### Create table

[Too large for Stack Exchange, here is a pastebin link.](https://pastebin.com/jvk4sRNS)

### ST_ClusterDBSCAN with different `minpoints`

```
drop table if exists buildings_cluster_test_result_mp5;
create table buildings_cluster_test_result_mp5 as (
    SELECT
        geom,
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(b.geom, eps := 5, minpoints := 5) over () AS cid
    FROM
        buildings_cluster_test b
);
drop table if exists buildings_cluster_test_result_mp2;
create table buildings_cluster_test_result_mp2 as (
    SELECT
        geom,
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(b.geom, eps := 5, minpoints := 2) over () AS cid
    FROM
        buildings_cluster_test b
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your examples the DBSCAN algorithm is working correctly.  The reason is that the `minpoints` parameter actually specifies the minimum number of close objects needed to *start* a cluster.  That is, a cluster is only created around an object which has at least `minpoints` objects within a distance of `eps` of it.

The `eps` distance you are using is fairly small relative to the distance between objects.  So for `minpoints` = 5, only the upper left cluster contains an item which has >= 5 items within distance `eps` of it.

The [ST_ClusterWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_ClusterWithin.html) function might provide grouping which is closer to what you require (although it is not yet available as a window function, only as an aggregate).

Comment: `ST_ClusterWithin` should be equal to`eps=0` for 99% of cases.